# Ionic 4 places generated pages outside of pages folder

Tags: angular7, ionic4

I'm creating my first Ionic 4\Angular app. In Ionic 3, pages generated in the CLI were placed in the "pages" folder. In I4 they're placed in the app folder parallel to the pages folder. If I generate them to be in the pages folder, or move them their after the fact,I get an "/GET" page error.

The reading indicates this is to stay consistent with Angular file structuring but I find it confusing.  Why have a "Pages" folder (with I4 creates by default) if Angular needs them elsewhere? What do I need to change if I want to Ionic to look for the pages in the Pages folder? It seems more logical to keep them there.

Answer (score 0):

Create the pages specifying the "pages" folder:

**ionic add page pages/YOURPAGE**

Answer (score 0):

Simply just got to your project root folder, open cmd or vscode terminal
and write

```
ionic g page pages/test
```

So now ionic will create a page, it will also create folder name- pages and now further you can do same with services,components,models etc

```
ionic g component components/xyz
```

Comment: Thanks you guys for your help. My question was more about the logic of where Ionic puts pages compared to I3.  I've figured out my /Get error now that I've worked with the routing in Angular a little more.